# Concurrent updates on Collection

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I am developing a System and it has `ArrayList` that access in several places(inserting, removing and updates the values). Due to access of `ArrayList` in several places when i run the program it gives Concurrent update error.

Instead of `ArrayList` I can use `Vector` because `Vector` is synchronized. But if i use `Vector` will It be cause to decrease the performance of the system? Give me Ideas. How I can solve this issue?

This is part of the exception I get:

```
].[localhost].[/uckt].[Faces Servlet]] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-144) 
Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_02]
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_02]
```

Comment: Do you access your arraylist from several threads? You can also get a ConcurrentModificationException if you remove items from a list while iterating for example (unless you use iterator.remove()).

Comment: yes. I am getting this error. So i wanted to prevent it.

Comment: In that case you probably don't need a thread safe variant of the an ArrayList - see [this post for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113016/concurrentmodificationexception-when-remove-element-from-a-java-util-list-while).

Comment: @PradeeGamage You should post the part of the code that throws the exception with a stacktrace to get better and more specific answers.

Comment: This is part of exception  ].[localhost].[/uckt].[Faces Servlet]] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-144) Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_02]
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_02]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one more thing: Your ConcurrentModificationException might not spawn from an actual concurrent modification through two Threads. There is another possible reason:

While iterating over the ArrayList, you might delete an element. If you try this

```
Object o = iterator.next()
if(someCondition)
    arrayList.remove(o)
```

in a single Thread, you will get a ConcurrentModificationException. In that case you will have to use ListIterator and it's remove method.

Comment: I think this will be cause. I will look into it. Thank You very much

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) ?

> A thread-safe variant of ArrayList in which all mutative operations
>   (add, set, and so on) are implemented by making a fresh copy of the
>   underlying array.

As ever, I would not worry too much about efficiency until you *know* it's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

See [Collections#synchronizedCollection(Collection)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedCollection%28java.util.Collection%29). This will return a synchronized `ArrayList` that you can use to safely add/remove/update elements in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can also synchronize your ArrayList on each access:

```
synchronize(myList)
{
  myList.add(object);
}
```