# Unexpected values while looping through Cayenne performQuery() results

Tags: java, foreach

This method returns a list of employee objects using Cayenne SelectQuery

```
List<Employee> getEmployees() {
  ...
  return getObjectContext().performQuery(query);
}
```

Now, I'm looping through the results

```
List<Employee> employees = getEmployees();

// test loop 1
for (Employee employee : employees) {
  //print out employee name
}

for (Employee employee : employees) {
  //print out employee name
  if (matchesSomeCondition) {
    employees.remove(employee);
  }
}

// test loop 2
for (Employee employee : employees) {
  //print out employee name
}
```

In test loop 1, it would show for example:

```
-John Smith
-Jane Doe
-Roger Wilco
```

In the actual removal loop, it would omit some people:

```
-John Smith
-Roger Wilco
```

Then in test loop 2 it would output everyone:

```
-John Smith
-Jane Doe
-Roger Wilco
```

When I change the removal loop to:

```
List<Employee> badEmployees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
for (Employee employee : employees) {
  //print out employee name
  if (matchesSomeCondition) {
    badEmployees.add(employee);
  }
}
employee.removeAll(badEmployees);
```

Then the loop works fine.  I just don't understand why I did not get an error or exception in the first example.  Even more bizarre is why the results are different in each of the test loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just looking at my old questions and saw this one still unanswered.

Removing employee triggered a callback in Cayenne that in turn added the employee back to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Java `for-each` loop isn't designed for manipulating the `List` it is iterating on. You need access to the `Iterator` in order to remove the current element. The `for-each` loop hides the iterator, so you cannot call `remove()`.

Hence, the approach you have chosen, thats the only way (with a `for-each`).

You can read more about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

Comment: I realized that I shouldn't be removing from the list while iterating through it, that's why I changed the code to remove after.  But I did not get an exception like this example: 

[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113016/getting-a-concurrentmodificationexception-thrown-when-removing-an-element-from-a[/link]