# How to remove a element from arraylist in android

Tags: java

I couldn't remove object.How can I remove a object from an arraylist?

## my code

```
 List<kisi> x=new ArrayList<kisi>();
 x.add(new kisi("1","betül"));
 x.add(new kisi("2","hatice"));
 x.add(new kisi("3","selma"));
 kisi k=new kisi("2","hatice");
     
 for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
 if (x.get(i).id==k.id) {
 Object obj = x.remove(i);
 break;
 }
 }
```

## my constructor

```
public class kisi {
 public static String id="0";
 public static String ad="0"; 
public kisi(String id,String ad) { 
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub 
this.id=id;
 this.ad=ad;
 }
```

Comment: when code run,it didn't enter if statement.And When I write elements of list,it write only one element third time.

Comment: Post your constructor for `kisi` class.

Comment: You need to edit the question to add it. There's a comment in there, so I can't tell what's on what line.

Comment: Ah ok: Remove the `static`s from your member variables in your `kisi` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Remove the `static`s from your member variables in your `kisi` class.

**But also note**

```
new kisi("1","betül")
```

So your `id` is a `String`.

When you go through the list comparing ids you do so with `==`.

`==` in java is a **same** comparison, not an **equal** comparison. This is unlike the behavior for strings in C# say.

So what you should do is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
  if (x.get(i).id.equals(k.id)) { //change here
    Object obj = x.remove(i);
    break;
  }
}
```

In this simple example this is not causing the problem because the two `"2"` strings are the same. Which leads me to conclude there's something funny going on your `kisi` constructor. This is the one I used and the code worked as was:

```
public class kisi {    
  public String id;    
  public kisi(String id, String string2) {
    this.id = id;
  }    
}
```

A constructor like this will break the code without the `.equals` call:

```
public kisi(String id, String string2) {
  this.id = id + string2;
}
```

Comment: I wan to write list element.it show only second element every iterator.for (kisi kisi : x) {       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"eleman"+kisi.ad, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }

Comment: Post your constructor for `kisi` class.

Answer (score 0):

To remove an Element safely from a list while traversing it you need to do it with an iterator. Otherwise you might get strange results!

[Calling remove in foreach loop in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196586/calling-remove-in-foreach-loop-in-java&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNHeelFjvfPiOr3H2dXL-bsZ7J80cg)

Answer (score -1):

In java the only method for removing an item from a list while traversing it is via Iterator.

Comment: What's this then: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int) or why doesn't that work in his case?

Comment: @weston please review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113016/getting-a-concurrentmodificationexception-thrown-when-removing-an-element-from-a

Comment: You appear to be saying that you **must** use an `iterator` and `iterator.remove` if you want to remove while going though a list. That's not true.

Comment: It's not a bad suggestion, but it's not the *only* method.