# Why does removing a non-existent element from a map during iteration only crash sometimes?

Tags: java, iterator, concurrentmodification

*Note:* this is not a duplicate of the many questions asking how to remove an item from a map during iteration.

I encountered some surprising edge cases when using a hash map iterator to remove an item from a map.

The following code crashes with with the a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put(1, 1);
m.put(2, 2);
m.put(3, 3);

for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> iterator = m.entrySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e = iterator.next();
    if (e.getKey() == 2) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
    m.remove(2); // This causes the crash
}
```

Unsurprisingly, the following code does not:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put(1, 1);
m.put(2, 2);
m.put(3, 3);

for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> iterator = m.entrySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e = iterator.next();
    if (e.getKey() == 2) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
    m.remove(4); // No crash here
}
```

However, the following code also does not crash:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put(2, 2);
m.put(3, 3);

for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> iterator = m.entrySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e = iterator.next();
    if (e.getKey() == 2) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
    m.remove(2); // Also no crash?
}
```

The only difference between the first and third examples are the removal of
the <1, 1> entry. Why does calling Map.remove only crash sometimes? Is this
specified in the standard anywhere?

Comment: A properly thrown Exception is *not* a crash. And this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113016/getting-a-concurrentmodificationexception-thrown-when-removing-an-element-from-a?rq=1 (see the 2nd answer). Also, read the [Javadocs on ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html). Relevant: *if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception.*

Comment: Try calling `iterator.next()` before the line that crashes. That might give you a clue

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I'm not modifying the collection, since the `Map.remove` call does _not_ change the contents of the collection in any of the examples.

Comment: @AAA you are modifying the map the line that does `m.remove(2); // This causes the crash` modifies the map. Since the iterator is still in a valid state, you get the exception

Comment: What do you mean by "since the Map.remove call does not change the contents of the collection in any of the examples"? Your first example removes element with key 2 which exist in map. I would say it is changing map.

Comment: But the map does not contain the value 2 at the point that `m.remove(2)` is called, which is my point.

Comment: Notice what I said in my last comment "The iterator is still in a valid state". It doesn't throw the exception if the element is found or not, but rather if the iterator is still in use

Comment: You call `m.remove(2)` on every iteration of the loop, so `2` exists in the map on the first iteration.

Comment: @Pshemo, if that was the issue, then why does the third example NOT raise an exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first example throws a `ConcurrentModificationException` because you are calling the `remove` method during iteration of the map.  The sequence of events is this.

1. Call `next()` to retrieve the entry (1, 1).  The key is not `2`, so don't call `iterator.remove()`.  Remove the entry with key `2` from the map directly with the call to `m.remove(2)`.  This changes an internal modification count that the `Iterator` expects to be constant.
2. Call `next()` to retrieve the next entry.  The modification count in the map no longer matches the expected modification count that was noted by the `Iterator` when it was created, so a `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown.

The last example doesn't throw it because `remove(2);` has no effect any more.

1. Call `next()` to retrieve the entry (2, 2).  The key is `2`, so call `iterator.remove()`, removing the entry.  This has the effect of modifying the iterator's expected modification count to match the map's modification count.  Calling `m.remove(2)` has no effect, because the key `2` no longer exists in the map.
2. Call `next()` to retrieve the entry (3, 3).  The modification count in the map matches the expected modification count that was noted by the `Iterator`, so no `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown.  The key is not `2`, so `iterator.remove()` is not called.  Calling `m.remove(2)` has no effect, because the key `2` does not exist in the map.

Note that the sequence of events above is valid for the current way that a Java `HashMap` iterates over its entries.  The keys happen to be retrieved in order.  In general, with any range of valid integer keys, the keys are *not* guaranteed to be retrieved in order.