# UnsupportedOperationException vs ConcurrentModificationExcetion

Tags: java, collections, concurrentmodification, unsupportedoperation

I have a code that adds data to a list. What I do not understand is why 
        the `UnsupportedOperationException` is thrown in one case and 
        `ConcurrentModificationException` in the other.
        I am adding data in list in both the case and then trying to remove list 
        data while iterating over the list.
        What i have read so far is that whenever any modification is made to 
        fail- fast collection,`ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown. So why this
        different behavior in both these cases?

```
  List<String> animalList = new ArrayList<>();
        animalList.add("cat");
        animalList.add("dog");
        animalList.add("bear");
        animalList.add("lion");

        Iterator<String> iter = animalList.iterator();

        while(iter.hasNext()){
            String animal = iter.next();
            System.out.println(animal);
            animalList.remove(3);
        }
```

This code throws `ConcurrentModificationException`

```
String[] strings = { "Java", "Honk", "Test" };

        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(strings);


        Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            String name = iterator.next();
            System.out.println(name);
            list.remove(3);
        }
```

while this one throws `UnsupportedOperationException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the code block, where you get `ConcurrentModificationException` , you get that exception because you created an iterator on `List` then removing directly from list from within loop so iterator has issues. You should use `remove()` method of iterator itself - [Iterator.remove()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()).

You should directly remove an element from list when removing from outside iterator loop. [See this another SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113016/getting-a-concurrentmodificationexception-thrown-when-removing-an-element-from-a)

In second case, with `Arrays.asList` , you get a `List` but actual list object might not be an `ArrayList`  and `remove(int index)` operation is optional at `List` interface. [See this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-)

All in all, as far as `UnsupportedOperationException` is concerned, in first case you are guaranteed to working with an `ArrayList` and for that class, remove operation is supported , [See this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int))

For second case, you can't be so sure. [Refer documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) of `Arrays.asList` where it says that returned list of fixed size so certain operations are not supported.

Comment: Iterator.remove()  didn't give the **ConcurrentModificationException**. So it means if i want to modify a collection while iterating over it, i should be using iterator's remove method not the class's remove method(in this case ArrayList)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.asList does not return an ArrayList. In fact, the list returned is not modifiable, thus when you try to modify it, it throws the UnsupportedOperationException.

Comment: To be more accurate, the list returned by `Arrays.asList` is modifiable, but it has a fixed size, so `add` and `remove` are not supported. On the other hand `set` is supported.

Comment: As you are saying Arrays.asList is modifiable but only the size is fixed,so if i remove an element and also add another element during the same iteration, the size remains unchanged.Then also why am i getting the same exception?

Comment: you can not remove items from the list returned from Arrays.asList, period. It has nothing to do with iteration at all.